# Modifying Android source to suit my business needs

Tags: android

As a proof-of-concept, I would like to create a reduced Android API, in order to force a certain behavior for applications at the API level, and in order to have only a subset of what the "clean" android offers. Actually, it's similar to having a custom ROM, with the exception of enforcing a set of rules over the developers.

Where should I start? can I legally modify the android source in order to change the developer API, or is it forbidden? Can I use the modified version for commercial purposes?

Maybe there's a more simple solution than changing Android's source, or should I start digging the repository and build my own version?

Thanks,
Harel

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not constructive. "Where should I start?" is too vague to be answered here, and the other questions you're asking are for legal advice about the license, which is not appropriate here. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe i didn't make myself fully clear, but aside the legal issues, I asked if modifying the source is not a drastic measure, and whether are there any easier solutions to fulfill the requirements of API & reduced set of capabilities.

Comment: I see four question marks in your entire question, and none of them follows anything that says "drastic measure", and I see a statement that says "Maybe there's a more simple solution" which is also not a constructive question. Saying "I need a different Android API than what's published." with no other information is too vague a requirement to even *suggest* an alternate solution to modifying the source.

Comment: Ken, unfortunately I can't be fully specific due to confidentiality issues. As I commented below, I want to make sure applications don't build their own UI, but use only elements defined by me or alternatively - only produce data reported to a global database (defined and used only by the OS) using the API that I will modify for that purpose. Hope that's specific enough.

Comment: my point exactly. You can't provide more info, and we can't possibly answer without more specifics. Therefore, your question can't possibly be answered here, and anything posted here in response is a discussion. Discussion questions are specifically mentioned in the [faq#dontask] as inappropriate here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I start?

http://source.android.com

> can I legally modify the android source in order to change the developer API, or is it forbidden?

Yes, so long as you abide by the relevant software licenses (mostly Apache License 2.0), and so long as you realize that you cannot license the Play Store and other commercial Google apps if you change the API in such a way that fails the Compatibility Test Suite.

> Can I use the modified version for commercial purposes?

Yes, so long as you abide by the relevant software licenses (mostly Apache License 2.0).

> Maybe there's a more simple solution than changing Android's source

Since it is unclear what you are hoping to accomplish, other than breaking a lot of apps, it will be difficult for anyone to answer this.

Comment: To be more specific, I want to disallow applications to build their own UI, but only to use a framework-based minimal UI elements, or write to a shared DB - using the API - with the data being used only by the OS itself selectively. Seems weird, but that's what the requirements define.

Comment: @HarelMoshe: Depending on where you are getting the apps from, and your legal rights with respect to those apps, you could use static analysis to validate that the apps are sticking to your constrained API set.